# My .Trash-0 is owned by root

Tags: root, trash

A folder in my home area, called `.Trash-0` is owned by root:

```
drwx------  4 root root      4096 Apr  8 10:03 .Trash-0
```

Should it be? Can I fix this with `chown`? Is it a problem?

Comment: So Why such question is downvoted?! Here's my +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These `.Trash-0` directories appear when root deletes non-root user files from a file manager. The 0 is the system $UID, which is zero for root. The directories are created any time a user deletes files belonging to another user account.

So I think you use your root account to delete some stuffs in your home using File manager not terminal.

And yes you can change ownership if you want or just delete it.

read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/why-does-home-trash-0-contain-duplicates-of-all-of-the-user's-files-875401/) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1282123.html) for more info