# Trash Has Reached Maximum Size

Tags: kubuntu, delete, trash, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and my trash folder won't accept any files larger than a text document. Yes, the trash is empty.  I've checked all the related threads here, as well as played with the size settings for the Trash folder in Dolphin, and I've spent a couple of hours on Google trying to find alternative solutions. All I've come up with so far is that this seems to be a somewhat Kubuntu-specific problem, and it's a real pain to resolve. Any ideas or should I just upgrade to v15.10 and hope for the best?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you put something into trash as root!

To access the Trash as root:

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Then type in the following command:

> gksudo nautilus /home/your_username/.local/share/Trash

You may need to install gksudo with:

> sudo apt-get install gksu

be sure to replace the "your_username" with your actually username!

Then delete everything in there (or just items you don't need)!

Comment: Really? When I trash files as root, they go into /.Trash-0

Comment: Well that works for me

Comment: wait maybe i typed it wrong lemme check

Comment: @SuperSluether look here http://askubuntu.com/a/635114/373012 the -0 is only when root users delete non root files

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @SuperSluether I thought I may have gotten it wrong.. glad its correct

Comment: I tried that command and it told me: 'Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated. please move it to /home/mike/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf manually'

Comment: when you tried which command

Comment: @Tornado118 try this :  just run      "gksu nautilus"    then navigate to the trash and delete the unneeded files

Comment: @Trevor Clarke It gave me the "Fontconfig..." warning when i tried the "gksudo nautilus /home/your_username/.local/share/Trash" command, and it told me the same thing when I attempted just "gksu nautilus." The file which dolphin is giving me a hard time about is on an external thumb drive which is a few years old, but I've used it before and never had any problems. And it's only 400 or so mgb, so I know the size isn't really an issue.

Comment: Strange.. @fabby could you help with this?

Comment: The issue is still unresolved, however recently I came across the same problem with a different thumb drive that I was attempting to delete files from. I was able to delete the small files and empty folders, but nothing larger than a couple mgbs.  So I'm guessing that it's strictly an issue with external hdds.