# What happens if you Trash the Trash?

Tags: files, delete, trash

I was just wondering what would happen if I went and moved the Trash located here:

```
/home/neo/.local/share/Trash
```

To my Trash? I mean if I go to that folder and right-click on the contents and tell it to move it to the Trash.

- What would happen as it would be trying to move itself inside itself?
- Is there another Trash it would move it into?
- And if so, what if I also Trashed that one?

Comment: Just try it out? ;)

Comment: Nope, I dont think you can trash the trash.. If you do, it will end up in the recycle bin :D

Comment: @ByteCommander: Moving one object inside of itself, while still having its outside remain outside itself, is impossible (at least in the dimension), so I didn't want to give it a go! :D

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes it is. Check out [Sphere inside out](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spheare%20inside%20out&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari%23safe=off&hl=en&q=sphere%20inside%20out).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Trash folder is first created when a user deletes a file. Within that folder are three directories:

1. `files`, where the deleted files are stored until the trash is
   emptied;
2. `info`, which stores information on where the files once were and when
   they were deleted;
3. `expunged`, to which files are briefly moved when the trash is emptied
   (but may contain some owned by other users from directories you
   deleted).

So whenever you delete a trash indeed you are calling recursively to create a new dir for the newly trashed files.

Also note that Trash exists for every user including the root account plus sometimes you could face some dirs names such as  `Trash-0` , `Trash-1`. Read my answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/619893/150504) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635099/my-trash-0-is-owned-by-root/635114#635114)

Answer (score 4):

You can trash files inside the trash (files inside `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/Trash/files/`). They will just disappear for a second and then come back to the same Trash folder.

When I tried to trash the Trash folder itself (or its subdirectory "files"), I got an error by Nemo file manager that it got an illegal argument. So this seems not to work (at least not with Nemo).